# NSUserDefafults returns wrong data

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsuserdefaults, osx-elcapitan

On my Cocoa application using Swift, I'm getting bad data from NSUserDefaults. If I go to the command line and do

`defaults read my.bundle.identifier`

It comes back with this:

```json
{  
    NSNavLastRootDirectory = "~/Documents";  
    NSNavPanelExpandedSizeForSaveMode = "{712, 521}";  
    producer = 10;  
    version = "-1";  
    when = 1470502459;  
}
```

Then, in my application I read the value of version like so:

```swift
let def = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let current = def.integerForKey("version")
print("Current version is \(current)")
```

It's printing out that current is 3, not -1.  What in the world is going on?

Comment: Are you sure it's an integer in the plist and not a string?

Comment: It converts it. Even if it were a string how would it get 3 instead of a failed conversion like 0?

Comment: It doesn't seem likely, I admit, but it's worth double-checking.

Comment: I did.  If you use NSUserDefaults to write a negative number, then it will show it in quotes in the preferences.  But it's still an integer on the way back.

Comment: Wrong bundle identifier?

Comment: Nope, not wrong.  I cut/paste.  And after the app runs and it resets to the new value, I see it in the same file I'm reading the defaults from.

Comment: I even removed ~/Library/Preferences/bundleIdent and verified there was not on in SyncedPreferences.  When I run the app it's still saying 3.  Where else could it be reading from?